# Google Maps layer copyright popup every time map updated / user input

Tags: openlayers-2, google, ios

I have used a Google Maps hybrid layer in Openlayers in my HTML5 iOS app for months now and it worked perfectly. Just recently they changed something because the 'Map data...' line at the bottom looks different (light grey background) and whenever you touch the screen or the map position is updated via navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() the map data copyright box pops up.

If anyone else experienced this, what solutions/workarounds have you found?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I saw this answer on the Openlayers mailing list a few days ago. You need to make sure you are providing a version, such as `v=3.6`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.6"></script>
```

Then it should disappear.

-- 
May 17, 2012 edit:

I just saw that this problem has returned on the `OpenLayers` mailing list. A suggested fix (which worked for me) is to paste the following into the openlayers `style.css`

```
.olLayerGooglePoweredBy.olLayerGoogleV3.gmnoprint {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is "legal" but i just made it go away with CSS.

```
.olLayerGoogleCopyright {display:none;}
```

## UPDATE

Apparently this [violates the terms of use](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.user/16571):

> By doing so, you violate the Terms of Use. Instead, you should use a
>   more recent version of OpenLayers - this problem was fixed in 2.11.

<s>Are you using 2.11? Apparently it's no longer a problem.</s>

## -- May 17, 2012 edit: (per celenius comment)

[TERMS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

> 8.5 Proprietary Rights Notices. You agree that you will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright
>   and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) that may
>   be affixed to or provided through the Service. Where such notices are
>   not affixed within the Service, you agree to display such notices
>   according to the Maps APIs Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers 2.11 is not compatible with the *current* “frozen” and “release” versions of Google Maps API. Either migrate to 2.12 RC5 or read this: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Release/2.11/GoogleMaps37.