# Using Google API 3 with Openlayers Brings POPUP

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, google-maps-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps layer copyright popup every time map updated / user input](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20604/google-maps-layer-copyright-popup-every-time-map-updated-user-input)

I recently upgraded from google map api v2 to v3. It was working quite fine previously but now it does work but each time I zoom,pan I get a popup. I had look at many thred and https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/how_to_get_rid_of_goggle_layers_map_data_windows one especially that explains that openlayes 2.11 has no problem (2.10 has problem and 2.11 being the latest I assume this). I am using openlayers 2.11 with geoext. How can I solve this problem?

[image: POPUP]

Comment: Do you have a live link to your map - it is much easier to debug with web browser developer tools....

Comment: I made a little test with OL 2.11 with GMaps v3 and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding version works for me too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.6"></script>
```

Adding this to CSS hides popup and 2nd copyright:

```
div.olLayerGoogleCopyright,
div.olLayerGooglePoweredBy
{
  display: none !important;
}
but Google links are still not clickable.
```