# How to turn off Google map data copyrighted window in Google Street layer (Qgis - Openlayers Plugin)?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close watermarks in openlayers plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24646/how-to-close-watermarks-in-openlayers-plugin)

After a few weeks not using Qgis, this morning I opened it up, accepted a request to update Openlayers Plugin. Right now, I found a window saying "Map data ©2012 Google, Mapabc" at the center of the screen, following me every where I drag the map. Any one experienced this, please tell me how to remove that screen?

I am using Qgis 1.7.4 on Windows XP, Openlayers Plugin version 0.90.

[image]